# Git benefits to consolidating (via symlinks) repeated images

Tags: git

Not sure how to write a succinct title on this but here's the situation -

We keep pushing a new version of something every week, and each new version has a new directory in the repo. Each new version has the same images as the previous version which is a bit redundant. I wanted to replace the repeating images with symlinks to a shared image to save space (we were pushing 500MB).

```
Old:
repo/v1/image1.jpg
repo/v1/image2.jpg
repo/v2/image1.jpg (same as v1)
repo/v2/image2.jpg (same as v1)
<...>

New:
repo/shared_images/image1.jpg
repo/shared_images/image2.jpg
repo/v1/image1.jpg -> ../shared/images/image1.jpg
repo/v1/image2.jpg -> ../shared/images/image2.jpg
repo/v2/image1.jpg -> ../shared/images/image1.jpg
repo/v2/image2.jpg -> ../shared/images/image2.jpg
<...>
```

This has definitely cut down on the overall size on disk when using `du` on the repository after it has been checked out which is nice.

I've been using git for a while but I'm unfamiliar with the behind-the-scenes magic. Are there really any other benefits to the consolidation I've made?

Say what you will about how this is totally bad practice to begin with, but I'd appreciate it even more if the actual question gets answered :)

Comment: You can symlinks files which are static to the git repo. Rather than making symlink to each image file, I would just symlink a whole folder.

Comment: Good feedback, it's likely that an occasional image won't be a repeat and there are other files in those versioned directories that are never repeats.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, you have identified the main benefit, a smaller working directory. Inside the git database, identical files will be stored as a single blob and be referenced as many times as needed, so there won't be any space savings on the git side.

Comment: You are correct that this workflow is not considered best practice, but I assume there is a very good reason why you have decided to use this model (reliable third party access to a rapidly evolving API topping the list of suspects).

You will likely find that adding a new version to the filesystem every week will grow to be unsustainable quickly (a year from today, you'll have to check out over 50 copies). As substantial changes to workflow usually take considerable time to plan and implement, I recommend considering your options so you have options should you reach that point.